# What is "src" for in HTML in the context of a responsive image?

Tags: html, src, srcset

The two following chunks of code are from a a Mozilla web development course. What isn't clear to me is the purpose of "src" when I already have "srcset". Can anyone explain please?

'''

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg"
     alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

'''

'''

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

src is the original attribute to specify an image. Today it serves as a fallback for legacy browsers.

Browsers use the srcset as the authority source if it is present and will ignore src. But if someone is using an old, unsupported browser like the 3% still using IE for some reason (honestly nothing can justify that choice), it will still be able to load the image.

So you asking why is very reasonable. I have actually debated removing it over the past month. I suspect I will in the next year or so.

Comment: Correct nothing can justify that choice but cockroaches are easier to kill than IE